# How to get notified of new questions with a certain tag by email?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the maintainer of cwru-ros-pkg, I'd be interested in getting notified by email of any new questions that are tagged with my repo name (or the stacks or packages contained therein). Is that possible?

I see the option called 'Entire forum (tag filtered):' in my profile->subscriptions tab, but it's not clear to me when it would choose to send me an email about a new question. I have some tags in my "Interesting tags" list - does it generate an email for any question with any of those tags?

What I'm really looking for is the ability to subscribe to a tag via email. For example, on Stack Overflow, if I hover over a tag, I get some information about that tag. One of the options in the little popup box is "subscribe", which I then configured to email me whenever a new question is asked or has that tag applied. Does the "Interesting tags" and "Entire forum (tag filtered):" options let me do that or is there some other way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9067/how-to-get-notified-of-new-questions-with-a-certain-tag-by-email?/) by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-02-15**:
Right now we're working on getting the email working. We hope to get email sorted out in the next few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes in your profile under subscriptions there is a line "Entire forum (tag filtered):" you can check off instant.  And then you can filter at the bottom either on interested tags only or exclude ignored tags.

We are working on getting the emails sent correctly they are not currently getting out of the server.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-16**:
Cool. And I got an email notification of your comment so it's working for me too. Thanks Eric.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-16**:
Yup. Been working for me since last night.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-16**:
Does the email functionality work yet?